# Would my fridge be causing the 20amp gfci to trip

Tags: wiring, gfci

I recently bought a house and when I went to plug the fridge in it worked fine however the next morning. I wen to check on it and found that the circuit had been popped as well the ice machine was on at during the night. The I turned the ice machine off and reset the breaker and plugged the fridge in and it worked for a while but it eventually tripped the 20 amp gfci this time and as well as the next time. I Will note that the fridge I self not plugged into a gfci but is wired from one could this be causing the problem or would there be other reason for the fridge to be popping the gfci?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/why-is-gfci-tripping-on-refrigerator-circuit, possibly a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

The fridge is most likely tripping the GFCI. Most folks recommend not plugging refrigerators into GFCI circuits, for this exact reason.

Refrigerator manufacturer's still have trouble controlling current leakage, and most of them are basically ignoring the problem. One day the manufacturer's will be forced to address the problem, but until then they'll likely keep tripping GFCIs.

Either run a non-GFCI circuit to plug the fridge in, or find a manufacturer that doesn't have the problem, and by a fridge from them.

Answer (score 1):

The compressor motor on the refrigerator (an inductive load) can cause GFCIs to trip even though there's no current leakage.  Although code requires other kitchen receptacles to be GFCI, the refrigerator can be on a regular non-GFCI receptacle.  The best thing is for the fridge to be on non-GFCI circuit by itself so there's nothing else potentially tripping the circuit and causing spoilage.