# Refrigerator Water Dispenser Tripping GFCI

Tags: water, gfci, refrigerator

The refrigerator is on a dedicated circuit / socket --- not a GFCI. However, in the last week, when using the water dispenser on the fridge, the GFCI has tripped simultaneously. There are no appliances on the GFCI that I am aware of.

[image]

Comment: Very confusing. When "the GFCI" trips, does the refrigerator turn off? If so, then it **is** on a GFCI. If not, then this doesn't make sense at all. Unless it is actually an **AFCI**. Can you upload a picture of "the GFCI" and list all the items that don't work when it has tripped?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is GFCI tripping on refrigerator circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/why-is-gfci-tripping-on-refrigerator-circuit)

Comment: Some outlets are sourced by the "LOAD" side of a GFCI.. Such downstream wiring is allowed, if confusing.  Its why new GFCI outlets have stickers for such downstream outlets.

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer. The refrigerator does NOT turn off when the GFCI trips, nor does the water dispenser stop working. The refrigerator is not even on a GFCI, but a dedicated circuit breaker/socket. The only things that don't work are the four sockets connected to the GFCI. And there is only a toaster plugged into one (not turned on at the time of the trip). The GFCI does not always trip, maybe only once or twice a week when using the dispenser.