# Can a fridge use a regular socket?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, socket, extension-cord

so I live in Norway, and I want to move my fridge to outside my kitchen as it's quite cramped, but the issue is that my fridge has a short cable and I either have to use a long extension cord or plug it into the socket that I now use for my TV and xbox. I could probably switch the TV and xbox to a different socket, but I'd probably need to use it for something else like my lamp instead.
So my question is, is there a safe way to do this?

Comment: Not sure about electrical codes in Norway, but one issue *might* be if the new outlet has GFCI (a shock-preventing device) that is triggered by the refrigerator compressor startup, shutting power. This can lead to spoiled food.

Comment: Most regular fridges use regular outlets.  The fridge should have a label on it saying how many amps/watts it needs, as long as it is below what the amperage of the circuit the outlet is on, it is okay.  Exp a 13 amp circuit on 220v has 2800 watts.  You want to keep it around 2000 watts or less to give some headroom.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Motor loads don't trigger gfci's.

Comment: @vidarlo, yes, motors are *inductive* loads, and when turning on and off, *frequently* trip GFCI's. Read: https://howtofixit.net/this-is-why-refrigerator-keeps-tripping-cfgi/, https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/why-would-a-gfci-trip-on-refrigerator-circuit

Answer (score 3):

Fridges can use normal sockets, yes.

If you use an extension cord, the most important thing to be aware of is that you don't bring an unearthed circuit into earthed environment, or opposite. In Norway, earth was not common outside kitchens, bathrooms and outdoors until past 25 years, thus there's a real risk of mixing.

It may also be that your fridge is connected to a non-gfci ("jordfeilbryter, jordfeilautomat") circuit, which means that it has somewhat better protection from power outage, at a cost to safety.

When it comes to extension cords, they're theoretically not permitted for permanent use. I would not worry about that in practice; use a high quality one (Ikea, Clas Ohlsson or similar, not eBay). Fridges are intermittent loads and quite low wattage.